# Loading data into html table using ajax and SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a stored procedure that selects all the fields in the table based on the date. I then created a method shown below to return the results as JSON.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetResult()
        {
            MonthNameConverter converter = new MonthNameConverter();
            string fullDate = converter.startOfMonth().ToShortDateString();
            string[] split = fullDate.Split('/');
            string date = "";
            if(Convert.ToInt32(split[0]) < 10)
            {
                date = split[2] + "-0" + split[0];
            }
            else
            {
                date = split[2] + "-" + split[0];
            }            
            var results = travelSOCC.GetLansingMileage(date).ToList();
            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

However when I go to append the data to an HTML table I'm getting an unidentified result.

```
$(function LoadData() {
            $("#LansingTable tbody tr").remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetResult")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON,
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (item) {
                        var rows = "<tr><td>" + item.TravelDate + "</td><td>" + item.TripType + "</td></tr>";
                        $("#LansingTable tbody").append(rows);
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.resonseText);
                    alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                }
            })
        });
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `GetResult` a `POST` method ?

Comment: Your action method is get but your ajax reguest is post.Default http verb for action method is get.

Comment: it was missing the `[httpPost]` but I added that and I am still receiving the same issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*unidentified result*"?

Comment: @Crowcoder I added more information in the original post, but basically its saying item.TravelDate is undefined, which I don't understand why that would be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify `$.each(data, function(item) {` as below:

`$.each(data, function(idx, item) {`

Please refer documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for more information.